conditional rendering in react + firebase
I want my code to conditionally render some pages after authentication but the current problem I am facing is they are rendering even without authentication. A user can access the pages without signing in
function App() {
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);
  const [userRole, setUserRole] = useState(null);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(async (user) => {
      if (user) {
        try {
          const userDoc = await getDoc(doc(db, 'users', user.uid));
          if (userDoc.exists()) {
            const userData = userDoc.data();
            setUserRole(userData.role);
            setIsAuthenticated(true);
            if (userData.role !== 'admin' && window.location.pathname.startsWith('/admin')) {
              navigate('/home');
            }
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error fetching user document:", error);
        }
      } else {
        setIsAuthenticated(false);
        setUserRole(null);
        navigate('/login');
      }
    });
    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, [navigate]);

  const handleLogout = () => {
    auth.signOut().then(() => {
      setIsAuthenticated(false);
      setUserRole(null);
      navigate('/login');
    });
  };

  const handleLoginSuccess = (role) => {
    setIsAuthenticated(true);
    setUserRole(role);
  };

  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        {isAuthenticated && (
          <nav className="nav-bar">
            <Link to="/home" className="nav-link">Home</Link>
            <Link to="/profile" className="nav-link">Profile</Link>
            {userRole === 'admin' && <Link to="/admin" className="nav-link">Admin Panel</Link>}
            <button onClick={handleLogout} className="nav-link">Logout</button>
          </nav>
        )}
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/login" element={<LoginPage onLoginSuccess={handleLoginSuccess} />} />
          <Route path="/register" element={<RegistrationPage onRegistrationSuccess={() => setIsAuthenticated(true)} />} />
          <Route path="/home" element={isAuthenticated ? <UserHome /> : <Navigate replace to="/login" />} />
          <Route path="/profile" element={isAuthenticated ? <ProfilePage /> : <Navigate replace to="/login" />} />
          <Route path="/admin" element={isAuthenticated && userRole === 'admin' ? <AdminPanel /> : <Navigate replace to="/login" />} />
          <Route path="/admin/manage-submissions" element={isAuthenticated && userRole === 'admin' ? <ManageSubmissions /> : <Navigate replace to="/login" />} />
          <Route path="/admin/manage-user-roles" element={isAuthenticated && userRole === 'admin' ? <ManageUserRoles /> : <Navigate replace to="/login" />} />
          <Route path="/admin/view-submissions" element={isAuthenticated && userRole === 'admin' ? <ViewSubmissions /> : <Navigate replace to="/login" />} />
          <Route path="/admin/notifications" element={isAuthenticated && userRole === 'admin' ? <Notifications /> : <Navigate replace to="/login" />} />
          <Route path="/admin/approve-reject-submissions" element={isAuthenticated && userRole === 'admin' ? <ApproveReject /> : <Navigate replace to="/login" />} />
          <Route path="/success" element={<ApplicationSuccessPage />} />
          <Route path="/*" element={isAuthenticated ? <ApplicationRouter /> : <Navigate replace to="/login" />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

the above is my App.js
and below is my index.js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();


I tried wrapping the index.js in BrowserRouter to fix the error below but when I do it renders everything  bypassing the authentication. and when i put my Router in App.js, the below error appears.
Error: useNavigate() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.
once I fix the the problem, the other problem is popping up. How can I fix this? is there an alternate way where I can use something else besides useNavigate without having to wrap it  in a Router component.

Are you saying that even when you're not authenticated, you can open up one of your protected routes without being navigated to /login?

Yes that is what is happening. Once I run the application its giving me access to all the protected routes as well

What debugging have you done? How have you verified the value of your isAuthenticated state?
